# Как правильно обработать файл invoice.xml согласно стандартам OIOUBL?

Tags: xml

я создал файл invoice.xml согласно всем стандартам OIOUBL что мне с этим файлом делать? создать таблицу в бд или отправлять на почту клиенту или еще что-то?

пробовал chatGpt, Claude-2, Bard